# Short gamma ray burst redshift

Tags: astronomy, gamma-rays

I would like to know what kind of methods are being used to infer the redshift distance of GRBs.

Some background: 
I recently went on two sites; [grbweb by IceCube](http://grbweb.icecube.wisc.edu/) and [Fermi GRB database](https://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/W3Browse/fermi/fermigbrst.html). On grbweb they give the redshift of GRBs but I found some weird values in them (a really high peak at 2000Mpc for short GRBs). On the Fermi website they do not give the redshift distance and I could not find a source to tell me how they would get it.

Comment: Do you mean how they get a distance from a redshift, or how they get the redshift in the first place?

Comment: How they get the redshift in the first place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gamma Ray Bursts happen in galaxies, and the ISM in the host galaxy will leave spectral imprints on the GRB afterglow spectrum. This also means that besides being interesting in their own right, GRB afterglows are also valuable light sources for various cosmological uses, including galaxy evolution and IGM analysis.